# PHP/HTML Line causing the page to go blank

Tags: php, html, mysql, crud

I really have no idea how to fix this.
Everytime I add this line of code to my php document, the page goes blank.
Has anyone encountered this issue before?

It's in a table. Apparently it's the **checked_id[]** array. Don't know how to fix it, it just causes the page to go blank when added.

```html
<td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name='.checked_id[];.' class="checkbox" value='.$row["id"].'</td>
```

Here's the whole block.

```html
 $output .= '  
<form name="bulk_action_form" action="delete_multiple.php" method="post" onSubmit="return delete_confirm();"/>
      <div class="table-responsive">  
           <table class="table table-bordered">  
                <tr>  

                     <th width="10%">Id</th>  
                     <th width="40%">Name</th>  
                     <th width="40%">Email</th>  
                     <th width="40%">Address</th>  
                     <th width="10%">phoneNumber</th>  
                     <th width="10%">appointmentTime</th> 
                     <th width="10%">appointmentDate</th> 
                     <th width="50%">message</th> 
                     <th width="10%">delete</th>
                     <th><input type="checkbox" name="select_all" id="select_all" value=""/></th>
                </tr>';  



                             if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
                             {  
                                  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
                                  {  
                                       $output .= '  




                <tr>  

                     <td>'.$row["id"].'</td>
                     <td class="name" data-id1="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["name"].'</td>  
                     <td class="email" data-id2="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["email"].'</td>
                     <td class="address" data-id2="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["address"].'</td>  
                     <td class="phoneNumber" data-id2="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["phoneNumber"].'</td>  
                     <td class="appointmentTime" data-id2="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["appointmentTime"].'</td>  
                     <td class="appointmentDate" data-id2="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["appointmentDate"].'</td>
                     <td class="message" data-id2="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["message"].'</td>
                     <td><button type="button" name="delete_btn" data-id3="'.$row["id"].'" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger                             btn_delete">Delete</button></td>
                     <td><input type="checkbox" name="'.checked_id[].'" class="checkbox" value="'.$row["id"].'"/></td>
                </tr>  
           ';  
      }                                   

 }  
 else  
 {  

      $output .= '<tr><td colspan="4">Data not Found</td></tr>';  
 }  


 $output .= '</table>  
      </div></form>';  
 echo $output;  
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not properly structured:

1. Missing close tag
2. Missing quotes

Use like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="'.checked_id[].'" class="checkbox" value="'.$row["id"].'"/></td>
                            ^            ^ ^ ^                        ^              ^^^
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. Also, I've already tried this. The one I've posted is just one of the altercations I made.

Comment: Have you removed semi-colon?

Comment: Yes, I have removed the semi colon.

Comment: I added this, and it seems to have displayed my functions. But I don't know if it's a valid structure. **checked_id [ ' ' ]**

Comment: what's that `checked_id[]` PHP array variable or you wanted to call that control by that name?

Comment: I think if it is control name, use like this: `name="checked_id[]"`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to `echo` PHP variables into HTML, you can't just write their names because HTML doesn't understand that. 
Here is the example in your first line, you gave same in most of your code. 
Your code:

```
name='.checked_id[];.' class="checkbox" value='.$row["id"].
```

How it should be:

```
name='<?php echo checked_id[]; ?>' class="checkbox" value='<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>'
```

Another thing, I think `checked_id[]` should be with an array index, you can't leave it empty. Correct me if I am wrong, and use this sample in your whole page because to display PHP variable you have to open HTML and echo your variable there like this `name="<?php echo $somevariable; ?>"`

try this :

```
<?php
$output .= "";
?>  
<form name="bulk_action_form" action="delete_multiple.php" method="post" onSubmit="return delete_confirm();"/>
      <div class="table-responsive">  
           <table class="table table-bordered">  
                <tr>  

                     <th width="10%">Id</th>  
                     <th width="40%">Name</th>  
                     <th width="40%">Email</th>  
                     <th width="40%">Address</th>  
                     <th width="10%">phoneNumber</th>  
                     <th width="10%">appointmentTime</th> 
                     <th width="10%">appointmentDate</th> 
                     <th width="50%">message</th> 
                     <th width="10%">delete</th>
                     <th><input type="checkbox" name="select_all" id="select_all" value=""/></th>
                </tr>';  
                        <?php


                             if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
                             {  
                                  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
                                  {  
                                       $output .= '  



                        ?>
                <tr>  

                     <td><?php echo $row["id"]; ?></td>
                     <td class="name" data-id1="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" contenteditable><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></td>  
                     <td class="email" data-id2="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" contenteditable><?php echo $row["email"]; ?></td>
                     <td class="address" data-id2="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" contenteditable><?php echo $row["address"]; ?></td>  
                     <td class="phoneNumber" data-id2="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" contenteditable><?php echo $row["phoneNumber"]; ?></td>  
                     <td class="appointmentTime" data-id2="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" contenteditable><?php echo $row["appointmentTime"]; ?></td>  
                     <td class="appointmentDate" data-id2="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" contenteditable><?php $row["appointmentDate"]; ?></td>
                     <td class="message" data-id2="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" contenteditable><?php echo $row["message"]; ?></td>
                     <td><button type="button" name="delete_btn" data-id3="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger                             btn_delete">Delete</button></td>
                     <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $checked_id[]; ?>" class="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>"</td>
                </tr>  

      }
```

Comment: Forgive me for not putting the whole code, but echo isn't necessary- set it up to be that way. I'll update the code. It's just the array that's not working.

Comment: yes because u was doing everything in php but u should separate them and use html for styling and php for coding